# How to use multiple callbacks when looping data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to get HTML form data, loop it through, change it a bit and insert it to database. I have tried like below app.js.

How can I make callbacks so that formdata what I have modified is available for .create function?

I have searched from everywhere and I always end up in dead end and undefined variable somehow.

app.js:

```
//Find the day where to save

Day.findById(req.params.id, function(err, day) {

if (err) {
  console.log(err);
  res.redirect("/diary");
} else {


// Search function to find data with _id

    function ingredientIdQuery(reqBodyId) {
      var ingQuery = Ingredient.find({_id:reqBodyId});
      return dbQuery;
    }


// This loops through HTML formdata and formats it for mongoose model

    for (var i = 0; i < req.body.amount.length; i++) {
      if (req.body.amount[i] !== "") {
          var amount = Number(req.body.amount[i]);
          var singleMealTempObj = {};
          singleMealTempObj.amount = amount;
          var _id = req.body.id[i];
          var query = ingredientIdQuery(_id);

 // Executing the query for the data I need with id
          query.exec(function(err, ingr){
             if(err) {
               return console.log(err);
             } else {
               singleMealTempObj.ingredient = ingr[0];
               singleMealTempArr.push(singleMealTempObj);
             }
           });         
        }
      }
    }


  // This inserts data into day

   Meal.create(singleMealTempArr, function(err, singleMealObject) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
     day.meals.push(singleMealObject);
     day.save();
     res.redirect("/day/" + day._id + "/dayshow");
    }
  });

});
});
```

Edit:
Thanks for reply and notices! While I was trying to do everything to get this work I missed those few things like declaring variables. Sorry for that. I threw the towel in to the cage at this point.

flow goes like this:
User sends HTML form data to app.js which is inside object of two arrays (id[] and amount[]). Amount array needs to be looped through if it has value other than 0. Same index id array value is used to fetch data from database. This data what is found from database with id from id[] is used with same index amount[] and it should be saved to mongo.

I can get the values from HTML form ok. but I have tried to make a search in Mongo in a for loop (query.exec in the code) I get the data ok. When I log the data outside the database query, variable is undefined.

I hope this clarifys a bit what I'm trying to achieve.

I'll continue this later... :)

Comment: So since your question has changed, you should select an answer for the previous question - then post a new question. This rewards the people who took the time to help you, and creates more searchable results so that everyone can benefit from the answers given.

Comment: Ok I'll do so. Thanks again for looking into this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess issue originates because of this function.

```
function ingredientIdQuery(reqBodyId) {
          var ingQuery = Ingredient.find({_id:reqBodyId});
          return dbQuery;
 }
```

Is find function asynchronous or synchronous?
Also you are returning dbQuery but dbQuery does not seem to be changed inside the function.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Yes there is typo. thanks for pointing it! I'm trying to make async callback so that i can loop through array, search db only with selected items in the array and save  found items in mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Couple I noticed that may fix this:

1. You never define singleMealTempArr, so when you try to push data to it, you are gonna run into problems.
2. Your ingredientIdQuery function returns dbquery - which also isn't defined. You actually call it ingQuery. Even so...are you positive that this will return the data that you want?

---

```
// lets loop through all the form fields in req.body.amount
for (var i = 0; i < req.body.amount.length; i++) {
      // keep going unless the form field is empty
      if (req.body.amount[i] !== "") {
          // assign all the form fields to the following vars
          var amount = Number(req.body.amount[i]);
          var singleMealTempObj = {};
          singleMealTempObj.amount = amount;
          var _id = req.body.id[i];
          var query = ingredientIdQuery(_id);
          // we are executing the ingredientIdQuery(_id), better
          // double-check that this query returns the result we are 
          // looking for! 
          query.exec(function(err, ingr){
             if(err) {
               return console.log(err);
             } else {
               singleMealTempObj.ingredient = ingr[0];
               // now that we've gone through and mapped all the form
               // data we can assign it to the singleMealTempArr
               // WOOPS! Looks like we forgot to assign it!
               singleMealTempArr.push(singleMealTempObj);
             }
           });            
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply and notices!While I was trying to do everything to get this work I missed those few things like declaring variables. The problem is

Comment: @Damii the problem is what?

Comment: Sorry for this. I meant to edit my original post. :)